# How to set different text in placeholder of my mat input in formArray?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a formArray in my mat-table where three rows are displayed. Now I want to have a different text for placeholder in each row in the column name, for example test1, test2, test3. What is the best way to implement this?

My Code:

```
<div formArrayName="rows" *ngIf="attributesWithFormControls.includes(column.attribute); else otherColumns">
                  <span id="edit-cell" [formGroupName]="i">
                      <mat-form-field id="edit-calc-input">
                        <label>
                          <input matInput type="text" [formControlName]="column.attribute">
                        </label>
                      </mat-form-field>
                  </span>
                </div>
```

```
  // To use input fields in template
  public attributesWithFormControls = [
    "productNumber",
    "name",
    "weight",
    "amount"
  ];
```

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.columns = this.displayedColumns.map(c => c.attribute);

    if (this.dataSource === null) {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
    }

    // myForm
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      rows: this.formBuilder.array([this.initItemRows()])
    });
  }
```

```
// Convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() {
    return this.myForm.controls;
  }

  get formArr() {
    return this.myForm.get("rows") as FormArray;
  }

  initItemRows() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      productNumber: [""],
      name: [""],
      weight: [""],
      amount: [""]
    });
  }
```

Here is my work in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac-6u6l2s?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REVISION USING FORM CONTROL**

If you wanted to do this from your `formGroup`, you could accomplish this with the following.

Create a helper function to return the placeholder text base on `index`

```
// return row placeholder
 getPlaceholder(i) {
   switch (i) {
     case 0:
       return "test";
       break;
     default:
       return "test" + i;
       break;
   }
 }
```

In your `addRow` function get the placeholder text and set it to the property `placeholder` in your `newItem.value` object

```
 addRow() {
   for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     const newItem = this.initItemRows();
     newItem.value["placeholder"] = this.getPlaceholder(i);
     this.formArr.push(newItem);
     this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.concat(newItem.value);
   }
 }
```

In your HTML markup access that property value from the `row`

```
<input
    matInput
    type="text"
    [placeholder]="row.placeholder"
    [formControlName]="column.attribute"
 />
```

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac-oxq4qq?file=app/table-basic-example.html

---

**REVISION NON FORM CONTROL**

Create a helper function to return the placeholder text base on `index`

```
 // return row placeholder
  getPlaceholder(i) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        return "test";
        break;
      default:
        return "test" + i;
        break;
    }
  }
```

In HTML markup via the `placeholder` attribute call the helper function and pass `i` as the argument.

```
<input
    matInput
    type="text"
    [placeholder]="getPlaceholder(i)"
    [formControlName]="column.attribute"
/>
```

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac-6aq6u6?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Modify your interface to include `placeholder` property.

```
// Interface
export interface MyInterface {
  attribute: string;
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
}
```

Add property with placeholder value to your column attributes array.

```
public displayedColumns: MyInterface[] = [
    { attribute: "productNumber", name: "ProductID", placeholder: "test1" },
    { attribute: "name", name: "Name", placeholder: "test2" },
    { attribute: "weight", name: "Weight", placeholder: "test3" },
    { attribute: "amount", name: "Price", placeholder: "test4" }
  ];
```

In HTML markup, use the `placeholder` attribute on the `matInput` and pass in your value via `[placeholder]="column.placeholder"`

```
<input
    matInput
    type="text"
    [placeholder]="column.placeholder"
    [formControlName]="column.attribute"
 />
```

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac-psmqzu?file=app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: What if I have the same attribute different placeholders? Name in row 1 would be test, row 2 test1 and row 3 test2. How do you implement this?

Comment: I think I understand your question now, please see revision to my answer.

Comment: see additional revision to use helper function via  `formGroup` newItems

Comment: Have another question. What is the possibility to show the placeholder in a row for the first cell only and hide it for the rest? Is it possible to influence placeholder with *ngIf?